# Calculating the price based on the product size

Tags: magento2

Our client has only one product which is product dimensions vary on the customer request. The product price dependent on the product dimensions. Therefore, we must calculate the final price based on the customer request.

So, my question is how we should do such kind of thing in Magento? Is it possible to get product dimensions while customers create an order?

Comment: Have you tried for custom options in product creating time?

Answer (score 1):

Magento provides event functionality for setting or change price while product is added to cart.
You need to put your logic into that event observer and set price according to that.

Comment: You have to give full answer with some example of event name related to this functionality, This answer need to give in details.

Comment: How we should into account custom options with this way? Because I need to calculate product dimensions that user were input.